# Get the most present elements from many fields

Tags: mysql, select

Here is my table:

```
id|item0|item1|item2
--+-----+-----+-----
1 | 10  | 12  | 12
2 | 12  | 68  | 13
3 | 15  | 13  | 10
```

I just want to get the most present number of all itemX columns. The query result should be: 12, 13, 10, 15, 68.

I know how to do this for one field:

```
SELECT item0 from finalBuild GROUP BY item0 ORDER BY COUNT(item0) DESC
```

But no for several at once.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by the  "most present number"?

Comment: Sorry my english is bad... Do you understand better: "the number which appears the most often in the table."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use derive table to aggregate all your column values in a single column and do ordering and counting in the derived table. Example below.

```
Select item0 as item, count(*) as cnt from
(SELECT item0 from finalBuild
UNION ALL
SELECT item1 from finalBuild
UNION ALL
SELECT item2 from finalBuild) as item
group by item0
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! I didn't know "UNION ALL".